# Failed solution for solving $\cos(\theta) = -\sin(-\theta)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm trying to solve  $\cos(\theta) = -\sin(-\theta)$ on the interval $[0, 2\pi)$,  but having trouble identifying what I'm doing wrong

$$\cos(\theta) = -\sin(-\theta)$$

By even-odd identities:
$$\sin(-\theta)=-\sin(\theta)$$

$$\cos(\theta)= -(-\sin(\theta))$$

$$\cos(\theta)=\sin(\theta)$$

Square both sides

$$\cos^2(\theta)=\sin^2(\theta)$$

By Pythagorean identities: $\sin^2(\theta)=1-\cos^2(\theta)$

$$\cos^2(\theta)=1-\cos^2(\theta)$$

$$2\cos^2(\theta)=1$$

$$\cos^2(\theta)=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\cos(\theta)=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$

$$\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{7\pi}{4}$$

I know the correct solutions are $\dfrac{\pi}{4}, \dfrac{5\pi}{4}$. Why am I missing $\dfrac{5\pi}{4}$ and in its place have $\dfrac{7\pi}{4}$ instead?

Comment: When you compute square roots you need to account for the fact that $(-1)^2=1,$ so $\sqrt{x^2}=\pm x.$

Comment: As a side note, observe that you can avoid the squaring and square rooting by dividing both sides of $\cos(\theta) = \sin(\theta)$ by $\cos(\theta)$ to obtain $\tan(\theta) = 1$, from which it's immediate that $\theta = \pi/4$ or $5\pi/4$. (To check that the division by $\cos(\theta)$ is OK, observe that if $\cos(\theta)$ were zero, then $\theta$ would be $\pi/2$ or $3\pi/2$, which doesn't satisfy $\cos(\theta) = \sin(\theta)$.)

Comment: $\cos ^2\theta =1/2 \implies \cos \theta =1/\sqrt 2, - 1/\sqrt 2$

Comment: I started typing a  "comment" when there were no comments or answers for this question.  By the time I had finished my 7 line comment, there were two other comments and three answers!  I type too slowly!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two of your steps cause issues

- It is true that $\cos(\theta)=\sin(\theta) \implies \cos^2(\theta)=\sin^2(\theta)$ but it is also true that $\cos(\theta)=-\sin(\theta) \implies \cos^2(\theta)=\sin^2(\theta)$.  This introduced the possibility of spurious results such as $\frac{7\pi}4$ or $\frac{3\pi}4$ and is which is is always worth checking results in the original expression.
- It is not true $\cos^2(\theta)=\frac12 \implies \cos(\theta)=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}$.  What is true is $\cos^2(\theta)=\frac12 \implies \cos(\theta)=\frac1{\sqrt{2}} \text{ or }\cos(\theta)=-\frac1{\sqrt{2}}$.  The second of these leads to $\frac{5\pi}4$ and the spurious $\frac{3\pi}4$.

Answer (score 5):

Well, first, a slightly different approach: $\sin(-\theta) = -\sin(\theta)$ since sine is an odd function. Thus, your original equation is identical to

$$\cos \theta = \sin \theta$$

Dividing by $\cos \theta$ on both sides (on the premise it is nonzero), you get that

$$\tan \theta = 1, \theta \ne \pi/2$$

This method of solving it might be more pleasant for you.

---

As for your solution, note that you need to account for the fact that

$$\cos^2 \theta = \frac 1 2 \implies | \cos \theta | = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \implies \cos \theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \text{ or} - \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$$

Moreover, squaring an equation introduces extraneous solutions which you might need to eliminate, which accounts possibly for your extra solution. For instance, $x=1$. Squaring this gets you $x^2 = 1$, for which not only $1$ is a solution but also $-1$. That is, $x=1$ implies $x^2 = 1$, but the converse isn't true (i.e. $x^2 = 1$ doesn't always mean $x=1$).

Answer (score 3):

It is very easy to miss roots when taking the square root.

You have correctly observed that $\sin\theta=\cos\theta$. Since this is impossible to be true when $\cos\theta=0$, the problem reduces to $\tan\theta=1$. Now you can use the fact that $\tan\theta$ is periodic.

Answer (score 1):

**Method-1:**
$$\cos(\theta)=-\sin(-\theta)\iff \cos(\theta)=\sin(\theta)$$$$\cos(\theta)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)$$
$$\theta=2k\pi\pm\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)$$$$ \theta=k\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}$$
Where, $k$ is any integer i.e. $k=0, \pm1, \pm2, \ldots$. For given interval $\theta\in[0, 2\pi)$, substitute $k=0, k=1$ in above general solution to get
$$\color{blue}{\theta= \frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{5\pi}{4}}$$
**Method-2:**
$$\cos(\theta)=\sin(\theta)$$
$$\cos(\theta)\frac{1}{\sqrt2}-\sin(\theta)\frac{1}{\sqrt2}=0$$
$$\cos\left(\theta+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=0$$
$$\theta+\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}$$$$\theta=\frac{(4k+1)\pi}{4}$$
Where, $k$ is any integer i.e. $k=0, \pm1, \pm2, \ldots$. For given interval $\theta\in[0, 2\pi)$, substitute $k=0, k=1$ in above general solution to get
$$\color{blue}{\theta= \frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{5\pi}{4}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\sin \theta = \cos \theta $

$\implies \tan \theta =1$

So $ \theta = nπ+ \frac{π}{4}$ where $n \in Z$

You want $\theta $ in $[0, 2π] $
Thus $\theta = \frac{π}{4}, \frac{5π}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos \theta = \sin \theta \Leftrightarrow \cos \theta - \sin \theta = \sqrt 2 \sin (\frac{\pi}{4}- \theta) =0$$
$$\frac{\pi}{4}- \theta = k \pi \Leftrightarrow \theta = m \pi +\frac{\pi}{4}, m \in \mathbb{Z}$$
From here you obtain all solutions in $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi)\Rightarrow \theta = \frac{\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{4}$